# Hough Circle on binary images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm trying to create a generic function which always finds my 3 color balls. (Red, yellow and white). I spend a lot of time to search a solution, and it's pretty hard...
For the moment, first, I use the Canny filter (I use the Otsu method to determine the lower and highter parameter) and I call the Hough Circle method by incrementing `param2` until I find 3 circles.

```
while (!findCircles){
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(hough, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, 200, low, 20, 100); //find3Circles = true;  
    if (circles.cols() == 3){
        findCircles = true;
    }       
    low++;
 }
```

It doesn't work very well...

If someone vote up for my question, i could post images (i have no enough points...) Please, if someone found the solution, it would be nice to tell me.

Comment: "It doesn't work very well..."

That's not much help.

Comment: I think most of us understand you can't upload the image however you could provide a better description of what 'isn't' working well since that is subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should base you method on finding colors, not shapes or at least you should stary with finding colors and then find shapes. [Here](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/) there is good(it uses old OpenCV API, but everything else is fine) article describing how to perform color based object tracking in OpenCV. The general idea is simple - convert image to HSV color space, use inRange function to find pixels which might be your objects and then track them (most likely you will have to filter the pixels - find biggest contour or contour which shape is close to circle). Note that you will need to call inRange function 3 times (one for each ball).